# Problem drupal with domain and redirection

Tags: redirection, .htaccess, domain-access, subsites

I have problem with drupal site when migrate it from dev to production. My website works fine until I tried to login as admin. After enter username,password ,and click login I got error page not found. Because I were redirected to a wrong path. For example. I were redirected to www.domain.com/cgp/user but the correct path should be www.domain.com/user. Bellow is actual screenshot. Does anyone have the same problem and know to to fix it? Thank you.
 [image: This is actual screenshot]

Bellow is virtual host config

`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com 
   ServerAlias domain.com 
   DocumentRoot "/root_directory"
   ProxyPass /  http://webserver_id/cgp/
   ProxyPassReverse /  http://webserver_id/cgp/
   ErrorLog "logs/cgp-error_log"
   CustomLog "logs/cgp-access_log" common
   # redirect non www to www
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in several areas, depending on your deployment method.

First of all, have you cleared your caches?  This fixes most issues, especially after importing a database.

It could be a server configuration issue, did you set it up or did someone else?  There could be version differences between the installed software on the dev and prod servers.

Lastly, have you tried setting the `$base_url` in your [settings.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=7.x)?

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I did set $base_url to my domain. Since I couldn't connect as admin to clean all the cached I connected to database and truncate all cache table but I doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: At this point, we're down to troubleshooting.  At this point, my first thought is that there is something performing the redirect.  Is there custom code performing a drupal_goto(), or is there a module performing a redirect (like logintoboggan or panels)?  What does your dev/prod stack look like (same machine, different, etc.)?

Comment: I developed the website on my local using XAMPP. After I finished, I copied all the code to webserver (apache2) `root_directory/cgp` and dump the database from my local to the sever as well. Then config database connection and base_url.

Comment: Follow is set up of virtual host in the server. due to security issue I changed the name the ip. Can you have a look? I think this problem was because of the virtual host setup.

Comment: I added virtual host config. Please check my question again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what cause the problem. I use another trick I saw someone suggest. I create a cgp symlink in cgp drirectory point to cgp directory itself. And it's work. I will need to test abit more but seem like this work fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  It definitely sounds like a misconfiguration *somewhere*, but there's no need to continue messing with it if it is functional now.